# how to link multiple xml files in python using DOM?

Tags: python, xml, dom, python-2.7, minidom

I have thousands of xml files with title and their description in different xml files. 
Example:

```
<entertainment id="12">

        <title>who is your favorite star?</title>
        <description>
               <male>Brad Pitt</male>
                   <female>Angelina Jolie</female>
            </description>
 </entertainment>
```

I want to create a web page using minidom in python to list all the titles having links to their answer page.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse('entertainment.xml')
questions = doc.getElementsByTagName('entertainment')
print "<ul><h1>Star Questions</h1>"
for n in questions:
    print "<li>" + n.toxml() +"</li>";
print "</ul>";
```

I have tried writing this code, which list the  titles. But couldn't make a link to the title to it's description page. And in that short description page, for example "Brad Pitt", i want to create a link and extract data from another xml file which has more information about Brad Pitt.

I am new to python, so not getting idea to make a link.

Comment: On a side note - Minidom is not the recomended way to deal with XML in Python - ElementTree is faster and easier to do.

Comment: but client's requirement is minidom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you want to achieve to your tag is wrong.
This is the correct hierarchy:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName('entertainment')[0].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].toxml()
```

Comment: Thank you @slashmili, my previous code is also working but i want to display in this format "12, who is your favorite star?" from the above xml file. Can you give me idea how to extract it?

Comment: And i want to make a link to the title "who is your favorite star?" which takes to another page to display "Brad Pitt". Can you give me idea?